# Receiving SIGABRT error when launching TTPhotoviewController in iPhone

Tags: c, xcode, three20, cloudmade, sigabrt

Well I'm creating an iPhone application which contains some features like Cycle routes and a Photoviewer.

For these Cycle routes im useing the Cloudmade api, and for the PhotoViewer im useing Three20's TTPhotoviewcontroller.

These Cycle routes map works perfect but i think it has todo something with the errors im getting.

I will describe 2 cases down here about what I tried and what problem I received.

**Case 1:**
Compiling goes wrong and receiving following error:

```
duplicate symbol _aatan2 in /Users/wesleycoppens/Documents/MooiWest/libs/Proj4/Device/libProj4.a(aasincos.o) and /Users/wesleycoppens/Documents/MooiWest/libs/route-me/Device/libMapView.a(aasincos.o)
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I am getting this error when i am trying to add to the Other linker flags the flag -all_load.
See the image below here how my Other linker flags currently look like.

see [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUTlk.png) for image: [image: http://i49.tinypic.com/262o7q1.png]

**Case 2:**
Compiling goes fine, app runs in simulator perfectly but receiving SIGABRT with device.

In this case I removed the flag -all_load in my Other linker flags. Now I am not receiving any compiling error, but I'm receiving a SIGABRT when tapping the tablerow which links to the photoviewer app.

I aint sure if I do link correctly to the Photoviewer to, so here is the part where I push the other photoview.

```
PhotoTest2Controller *photoViewController = [[PhotoTest2Controller alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photoViewController animated:YES];
[photoViewController release];
```

Also here another screenshot of the linker flags how they are defined in this case:

see [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unaYc.png) for image:
[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/vhuv0z.png]

Answer (score 1):

finally I found a solution for this. Instead of using "-all_load" tag you can use "-force_load path_to_library/libXXX.a" in all the libraries you need except the one you get the duplicate error. It worked for me! Hope it helps.